# Powershell: Write inline log instead of writing value to the host

Tags: powershell, docker

There are two powershell scripts Script1 & Script2.
Script1 has Docker exec command which calls Script2.

Script1:

```
$output = ExecutePS2InDocker -command "FromScript2 $(varName)"
```

Script2:

```
function FromScript2 (name){
  Write-Host "method-called";
}
```

**Actual Behavior**:
Powershell dumps the output of script 2 to the host (Script1) by default. Hence $output in Script1 is set to "method-called" log message.

**Expected Behavior**:
Script2 should only print the message in the console. And it should not return the value back to the host i.e Script1
May I please know whether inline console logging is possible in Powershell without returning the log message back to the host?

Comment: Sounds like `ExecutePS2InDocker` (whatever that is) is scraping the console output from your container and turning it into regular pipeline output.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for pointing out. I added a flag to split the scrapped output.
Ex: $output = ExecutePS2InDocker -command "FromScript2 $(varName) -split ' '"

this workaround helped.